# How can I tune this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MySQL query which works, but it is quite slow. Is anyone able to help me improve the speed of the following query?

```
    SELECT *
    FROM vtiger_accounting va 
    INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity vc
    ON va.accountingid = vc.crmid  
    INNER JOIN vtiger_servicecontracts vs
    on   va.accountingrelated2=vs.servicecontractsid
    INNER JOIN vtiger_servicecontractscf vsf
    on       
    vsf.servicecontractsid=vs.servicecontractsid

    WHERE vc.deleted=0 AND va.accountingid > 0
    and va.accountingstate='Pending'
    and accountingtype='Pelunasan TB'
```

Comment: Are any of the columns you're querying on indexed?

Comment: yes they are indexed

Comment: Also check data types of fields you equate to join..avoid select *..select fields which matters to you.

Comment: about the syntax is they proper or i should change?

Comment: Your question was difficult to read and had some grammatical issues, so I hope you don't mind that I fixed it up. This will help you get the answers you are looking for hopefully.

Comment: Can you run an EXPLAIN of this query and post the results of it. With this we can check it is actually using the indexes you have set up.

Answer (score 0):

"They are indexes" -- That probably means that each one in indexes.  This is *not* the same as a "composite" index.  The following would be much better (assuming that `accountingtype` is in `va`):

```
INDEX(accountingstate, accountingtype, accountingid)
```

The first 2 (all with '=') can be in any order; the last one ('range') must be after the others.

The fact that `deleted` is in a different table makes it hard to optimize that part.  However, this *may* help:

```
INDEX(deleted, crmid)
```

[More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Recommend you spell out the columns you really need, not `*`.